# Warning about battery when using Core Location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager, core-location

I see a lot of apps that use GPS in the iPhone have the following warning in the App Description:

Warning: Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life.

If an App uses the background processes (like startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges or Region Monitoring) Apple suggested that the battery life would not be affected significantly. So if I use these background location services, do I still have to have this warning in my App Description?

Is there any guideline from Apple for this? What do people generally use as a "Best Practice"

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/325-how-to-effectively-use-core-location-in-your-iphone-app/

Usually, you don't want to update the user's location until you REALLY need it, or the app will only be running for a few minutes (like the app to find your parked car).